# image upload using multipart retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-upload

Actually, I'm new in this field.facing some problem during image upload.the process automatically suspended after some time.I am attaching my code below.Please anyone helps me to solve this problem.

***ServerResponse.java***

```
public class ServerResponse {

// variable name should be same as in the JSON response from PHP

@SerializedName("success")
boolean success;
@SerializedName("success_msg")
//@SerializedName("message")
String message;

String getMessage() {return message;
}

boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}
}
```

***ApiClient.java***

```
 public class ApiClient {



// public static final String BASE_URL="http://www.mytriangle.net16.net";
  public static final String BASE_URL="http://bsenterprise.in/webservice/";
 // public static final String BASE_URL = "http://mushtaq.16mb.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static int unique_id;



public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

***ApiService.java(Interface class)***

```
public interface ApiService {


@Multipart

@POST("imageupload-1.php?")
//@POST("retrofit_example/upload_image.php")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(
                                @Part MultipartBody.Part file1,
                               // @Part MultipartBody.Part file2,
                               //
                               // @Part("file") RequestBody name,
                               // @Part("serial_no") int serial_no);
                                @Part("serial_no") int serial_no);

}
```

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnUpload, btnPickImage;
String mediaPath;
ImageView imgView1,imgView2;
String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public static int choice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");

    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    btnPickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_img);
    imgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview1);
    imgView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview2);

    choice=0;

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadFile();
        }
    });

    imgView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            choice=1;
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);
        }
    });

    imgView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            choice=2;
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            // Get the Image from data
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
            if(choice==1) {
                imgView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                cursor.close();
            }

          /*  else if(choice==2) {
                imgView2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                cursor.close();
            }  */

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image/Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}



// Uploading Image/Video
private void uploadFile() {
    progressDialog.show();

    // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
    File file1 = new File(mediaPath);
   // File file2 = new File(mediaPath);

    // Parsing any Media type file
    RequestBody requestBody1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file1);
   // RequestBody requestBody2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file2);

    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file1.getName(), requestBody1);
   // MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file2.getName(), requestBody2);

    RequestBody filename1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file1.getName());
   // RequestBody filename2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file2.getName());

    ApiService getResponse = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
   // Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.uploadFile(fileToUpload1);
    Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.uploadFile(fileToUpload1,24);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(file1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
            if (serverResponse != null) {
                if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                assert serverResponse != null;
                Log.v("Response", serverResponse.toString());
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

***In Dependencies***

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

***Manifest Permission***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

***Android Monitor output***

```
11-03 14:31:07.404 13163-13163/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
11-03 14:31:07.584 13163-13163/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-03 14:31:07.724 13163-13163/? I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
11-03 14:31:07.724 13163-13184/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-03 14:31:07.734 13163-13163/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
11-03 14:31:07.744 13163-13163/? D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
11-03 14:31:07.784 13163-13184/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.4_RB1__release_AU (Ic8ede1fb34)
                                           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
                                           Build Date: 12/10/15 Thu
                                           Local Branch: mybranch17178083
                                           Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.4_rb1.30
                                           Local Patches: NONE
                                           Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
11-03 14:31:07.784 13163-13184/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-03 14:31:07.804 13163-13184/com.example.atanu.imageview D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-03 14:31:07.894 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b1dad79 time:103294123
11-03 14:31:14.813 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:103300687
11-03 14:31:23.323 13163-13173/com.example.atanu.imageview W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.429ms
11-03 14:31:24.283 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b1dad79 time:103310156
11-03 14:31:26.602 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-03 14:31:27.292 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
11-03 14:31:27.372 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-03 14:31:28.002 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
11-03 14:31:28.012 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-03 14:31:29.292 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Choreographer: Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-03 14:31:29.342 13163-13184/com.example.atanu.imageview V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
11-03 14:31:29.362 13163-13184/com.example.atanu.imageview V/RenderScript: 0xb83d1510 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
11-03 14:31:29.992 13163-13163/com.example.atanu.imageview I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: paste the full error stacktrace

Comment: actually shows no error.run suceesfully.I can choose image file from gallery.after then when click upload button the preogress button continuously rotating and don't give any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upload your file like this

```
File file1 = new File(mediaPath);
int id=24;
// File file2 = new File(mediaPath);

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file1);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", file.getName(), requestFile);

RequestBody requestBodyid = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),id);


ApiService getResponse = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
// Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.uploadFile(fileToUpload1);
Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.uploadFile(body,requestBodyid);
```

instead of

```
RequestBody requestBody1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file1);
```

**EDIT:** You forgot to create request body for the id. Add these to the code.

```
RequestBody requestBodyid = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), id);
```

Where id is your id, i.e id=24.

Comment: I try with the changes as u said.but still have the same prblm .

Comment: I also try this but still upload failure.should i change smthng in interface class also for this?but it don't takes id as a int in "RequestBody requestBodyid = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), String.valueOf(id));".that's why I parse it into string.but still not working.

Comment: thanks boss! image uploaded successfully...one more thing can u please tell if I want to upload 2 images using 2 image view with a single button click then whats should I change in interface class and upload() function.?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that progress bar is not getting hidden, you are not calling `progressDialog.dismiss();` in `onFailure` function.

Comment: Yeah I add this in onFailure and yes the image uploading in failure.can u please tell me what's the error in this code. in the interface class I pass a int variable named serial_no to insert the picture in the particular row in the database.so is it right way to pass the parameter in multipart.

Comment: your stacktrace doesn't contain anything. Try uploading again and then capture the error stacktrace and paste here.

Comment: nothing displayed in error stacktrace during run.it's totally clear.but in verbose it display the same message which I mention above.

Comment: You have to enable logging in retrofit. See this : https://caster.io/episodes/retrofit-2-configuring-http-logging-interceptor/