# Retrofit image upload Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am uploading an image with retrofit multipart api. i am getting success in postman but getting below error in code :

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=422, message=Unprocessable Entity,
>   url=http://upload-snack.13.251.251.232.nip.io/upload}

**Postman :**

[image]

**Retrofit code :**

Request :

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Interface :

```
 public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context, String baseURL) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Activity class code :

```
 private void uploadToServer(String filePath) {
        Retrofit retrofit = ServiceGenerator.getRetrofitClient(this, "http://upload-snack.13.251.251.232.nip.io/");
        Api uploadAPIs = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        //Create a file object using file path
        File file = new File(filePath);
        // Create a request body with file and image media type
        RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        // Create MultipartBody.Part using file request-body,file name and part name
        MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), fileReqBody);
        //Create request body with text description and text media type
       // RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "image-type");
        //
        Call call = uploadAPIs.uploadImage(part);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                Log.e("response", response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("failure", "failure");
            }
        });
    }
```

I have checked below tutorials/answers but nothing works :

- https://android.jlelse.eu/working-with-retrofit-825d30348fe2
- https://inducesmile.com/android/android-upload-image-to-server-using-retrofit-2/
- [image upload using multipart retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091729/image-upload-using-multipart-retrofit-2)
- [Upload image into server using retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016082/upload-image-into-server-using-retrofit)
- https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-upload-file-tutorial/
- https://www.journaldev.com/23738/android-multipart-image-upload-progress-retrofit-nodejs
- [Image upload using retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51104236/image-upload-using-retrofit?rq=1)
- [How to Upload Image file in Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Retrofit 2 Multipart image upload with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553210/retrofit-2-multipart-image-upload-with-data)
- [POST Multipart Form Data using Retrofit 2.0 including image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)
- [Retrofit Uploading multiple images to a single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866676/retrofit-uploading-multiple-images-to-a-single-key)

And many more.....

But still not working. Please help

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find the solution for this? Please let me know if there are any solutions.

Comment: @Akshay need to change media type to image/png instead of multipart/form-data. That will work.

Comment: @VishvaDave Thankyou very much, it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

Change Media type image/* instance of multipart/form-data. i think this will help you.

```
 File file = new File(filePath);
    // Create a request body with file and image media type
    RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    // Create MultipartBody.Part using file request-body,file name and part name
    MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), fileReqBody);
```

Comment: are you sure key name is "image"

Answer (score 2):

Change your Retrofit interface methode to this.

```
public class ServiceGenerator{

    private static final String BASE_URL = "base_url";


    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in Kotlin but thanks to @VishvaDave. So I did it in this way

```
val file = File(filePath)
val fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file)
val part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, fileReqBody)
```